# Logistic regression with SGD getting low error with high learning rate

Tags: regression, logistic, python, numpy

The thing is that I am implementing LR with SGD.
Here is my cross error function:

```
def crossErr(x,y,w):
sz = len(x)
error = 0
for i in range(sz):
    error += np.log( 1 + np.exp(-y[i]*(w.T.dot(x[i]))))
return error/sz
```

Where *x* are the set of features, *w* the weights and *y* the labels.
Then I have the gradient of the cross error as follows (same parameters as above):

```
def gradLR(x,y,w):    
    sz = len(x)
    err  =0
    for i in range(sz):
        err += (y[i]*x[i])/(1 + np.exp(y[i]*w.T.dot(x[i])))
    return -1*err/sz
```

As last this is my SGD_LR function:

```
def sgdRL(X,Y,lr,it):
epoch = 0
n_groups = len(X)//16      
w1= np.array([ 0 ,0  ,0])
w_old = w1
norm=1
k=0
mX = np.array_split(X,n_groups)    
mY = np.array_split(Y,n_groups)   
while k < it and norm > 0.01:
    np.random.seed(k)
    p = np.random.permutation(len(mX))
    w1 = w_old
    for o in range(n_groups): 
        index= p[o]
        w_new = w_old - lr*gradLR(mX[index],mY[index],w_old)
        w_old = w_new

    norm = np.linalg.norm(w1 - w_old)
    epoch+=1
    k+=1
           
return w_new,epoch
```

Where *X,Y* are the data set, *lr* is the learning rate, *it* is the number of epochs.
The algorithm split the data set in minibatchs and update the weighs every time it use a minibatch to compute de gradient.

Everytime it iterate on all minibatch,I count 1 epoch, and the I shuffle the data set and begin a new epoch.

The thing I am doing is very simple: I am genenerate a  cloud of 100 points and classify them with respect to some arbitrary line, and no noise is included.
Then I train my model with this data set and use a sample with 1000, with the same seed (I mean same distribution) points as a test set.
The thing is that if a choose a high learning rate, I obtain a very low error (I have come to use lr=1000)
That is counter-intuitive, based on theory.

What could be happening?

The source code can be found at: https://github.com/Dazckel/Cositas/blob/main/proof.py

Comment: Have you compared your results to those produced in a standard library? This comparison might help turn up any bugs or discrepancies.

Comment: you break if the weight delta is too small. But using a small learning rate your weight change will be small.

Comment: ie you need to change your stopping condition to something like norm of gradient, not norm of weight delta

Comment: @seanv507 I know what you mean but that is not the problem. The point is that a higher learning rate should not get better error.

Comment: No I dont think you understand - I am explaining why you are seeing this behaviour. the reason a higher learning rate is getting a better error is because your stopping condition will stop straightaway (after 1 iteration) for a small enough learning rate. You do not give the algorithm a chance to converge (for small learnig rates), because you insist that the weight change must be of a certain size.. (similarly stopping after a certain number of iterations has the same problem, that the smaller the learning rate the more iterations you need to converge.

Comment: @seanv507 that's right, if I remove the condition a lower lr will converger but, again, that is not the point. What I mean is, due to the convexity of the function, a high lr should never converge, ie a lr=1000 should diverge and not get lower error. At least that what I was told in theory. Could it be that the function is not convex?